# SDL Web 8.1.1 Search si4t not working failed during publishing

Tags: publishing, web8, deployer, si4t

1. successfully setup solr 4.3.1
2. configured the solr cores and the URL is working as expected
3. updated the cd_storage_conf
4. added SearchDAOBundle reference
5. updated the Storage Type pointing to  com.tridion.storage.si4t.FSSearchDAOFactory
6. added Indexer to the Storage Type

Where can we find the si4t, si4t-solr.jar files for SDL Web 8.1.1 and the dependent jar files.

[image]

Comment: I also checked following link https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/wiki/SI4T-Solr-Configuration-101

Comment: refer to http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-814D5C17-9320-4BC4-B50B-6CC007D79C32  , this was for web 8 , this issue is for In order to install SI4T in a SDL Web 8 deployer, you must install hotfix CD_8.1.0.1418. Contact the SDL Customer Support to learn where you can obtain the hotfix. but the version we are using is 8.1.1 , Copy si4t-solr.jar and its third party library dependencies from deployer\lib\si4t-solr to the lib folder of your deployer application. we don;t find si4t-solr folder at all.

Comment: I tried all options no luck. please let me know if any of you have made si4t work for sdl web 8.1.1

Comment: Can you share your cd_storage_conf?